# In-built function to return first parameter if second is true, or vice versa

Tags: php

One day I was going through functions in the php manual and found a pretty stupid function with pretty weird name. All the function did was return the second parameter if first one was true. I never thought I'd ever need something like that.

Nevertheless , today I want to use that function. I know that this is a pretty simple function and same behavior can be mimicked by a UDF, but since I believe native implementation is always better than UDFs, I'd like to use the real function.

Comment: And what did it return otherwise?

Comment: Don't really remember, but if I had to guess, I'd say an empty string or false or the first parameter itself!

Comment: Well, even if such a function exists, it's equivalent to `a ? b : ""`.  Hardly seems worth a function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably referring to the ?: operator that has been added in PHP 5.3. It works like this:

```
var_dump(true ?: "foo");  // true
var_dump(false ?: "foo");  // foo
```